# gcp metric vibrates in small scale

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, metrics, google-cloud-metrics

[image]
This is my es workload's metric and it's vibrating somehow. But when I scale-up the metric, it'll be stationary as below:
[image]

Each of pods is stationary even in small scale:
[image]

How can I make it stationary? I can't find any documentation about this and logs. thanks

Comment: Hello, which gke version are you running? have you seen this: [GKE Fluctuating Metrics Reported After Upgrade](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158039186) ? It might be related to your issue.

Comment: @willrof ahh..! fluctuating! I couldn't come up with that for googling.. and yeah! that's it. you saved my uncomfortableness. If I could choose your answer, I would. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've created an answer and I'd appreciate if you could vote for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GKE metrics default behavior on previous versions was to report the metrics every 2 minutes.

The version 1.16 uses a different metrics agent to export that data and this is the reason why it's showing that way because the data is not being exported at the same time.

The issue is on the graphs, not on the deployment itself as fair as I can see.

This is currently a work in progress, but you can follow the resolution of this issue on this link:

- [GKE Fluctuating Metrics Reported After Upgrade](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158039186)